# Why does reordering turn single column data frames into vectors?

Tags: r

I am just curious why reordering a single columned data frame (or matrix) converts it into a vector. Is there any reason for this?

```
k <- data.frame(a=c(2,10,3), b=c(8,3,9))
k <- k[order(k[,1]),]
class(k)
# [1] "data.frame"

k <- data.frame(a=c(2,10,3))
k <- k[order(k[,1]),]
class(k)
# [1] "numeric"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at `?'['` In particular, the `drop` argument

```
drop: For matrices and arrays.  If ‘TRUE’ the result is coerced to
      the lowest possible dimension (see the examples).  This only
      works for extracting elements, not for the replacement.  See
      ‘drop’ for further details.
```

To answer your question, you want

```
k[order(k[,1]), , drop=FALSE]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is my second question with answer in this help document. I should read it!